# Date difference in PHP to update the mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to log the time difference in a mysql-field and when I try on screen the values are correct. After submitting the field to the database the field is empty.
Where do I go wrong?
The field is declared in mysql as timestamp and format current_timestamp.
The code:

```
$strStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
sleep(5);
$strEnd   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$dteStart = new DateTime($strStart);
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd);
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
//$calc = $dteDiff->format("YYYY-%M-%D %H:%I:%S");
$calc = $dteDiff->format("%Y%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S");
echo "Difference: " . $calc;
```

I am submitting the $calc to the db.

Comment: You are not putting anything in a database in the code you have shown. And what is the result of your `echo`, is that what you need?

Comment: A difference between two timestamps is not a date/time.... dates/times represent a fixed point in time, not a period of time or a duration of time.

Comment: What type of column in db table where you inserting data?

Comment: It is a timestamp field and my code for updating is:
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO refTrackLogs (refTrackId, refPointId, name, floorId, refType, latitude, longitude, logtime) VALUES ('$data[id]', $bpoint, '$b[label]', '$b[floor]', 'calculated', '$b[latitude]', '$b[longitude]', '$calc')");

Comment: Can I make the difference a legal date and time?

Comment: Yes, the echo part works with 5 secs difference:
0000-00-00 00:00:05 and this is what I want the time to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySQL dates have a minimum value of `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'`, you cannot store this value (`'0000-00-00 00:00:05` for 5 seconds) as a date/time value.... nor should you, because it isn't a date/time..... date/time is a fixed point in time, not an interval, which is the period between 2 date/times. There is no specific datatype for a date interval.

I would suggest storing the actual date/time value rather than the interval, and only calculating the interval when you need to do so.
Alternatively, if you must store the interval itself, then store a number of seconds as a float rather than trying to force it into a formatted an inappropriate datatype; so store `5.0` seconds instead.